# How can I remove the side menu in the Samsung AVD skins?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I have recently discovered the great [Samsung skins for AVD](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/overview.html), however, there is a **HUGE** side menu that I do not want, since I can already do its functions with the device itself.

Does anyone know how to remove this side menu?

Best regards :)

[image: Samsung skin with its huge menu to the side]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone struggling with this, I ended up creating [my own skin for the Galaxy S20 Ultra](https://gofile.io/d/VTR2VG) overwriting the original.

[image: My new own S20 Ultra skin]

Feel free to use it for reference or as you please!

Happy coding :)